# VBA Write Very large string

Tags: vba, binary, hex, basic

So I have a large vba string I am trying to write as binary to a file.  I have a function which does so beautifully.  I have a string which is very long, about 80k lets say.  This string reads in from a file correctly, passes through functions correctly, prints to screen correctly.  But no matter what I do, in any way shape or form can i get more than 39k into the file. I have split the string into smaller bits figuring this is a VBA limitation.  Then passing it to my fuction 42 characters at a time.  Seek(LOF) +1 put is what im doing after open bin but... It doesn't seem to matter how I call it. Binary, ASCI, writing it all at once. I only get the last 39k. Here is the function im using to write to file.  This is a memory limitation not a grammar error as far as I can tell and probably has little to do with the form of my code as much as some thing I seem not to get.

```
sub IBorrowedThis(hex_val as string)

dim output() as string
dim handle as long
output = Split(hex_val, "|")
handle = FreeFile
open "fp" for binary as #handle

For i = LBound(output) to Unbound(output)

seek #handle,LOF(handle) + 1
  put #handle, , cbyte("&H" & output(i))
next i

close #handle

end sub
```

So I have tested this all in pieces and everything works.  appending to the end included.  just not for large files.

Comment: `Dim i as Long`, otherwise it's Variant and Integer. Write `Ubound` instead of `Unbound`.

Comment: I can't replicate this with the code provided. Changed `i` to `Long`, fixed the typo in `UBound`, generated 100KB worth of pipe delimited bytes in a single `String`, then passed that to your? "`IBorrowedThis`" procedure. This created a new file of the expected size, and when run again, appended with no issues. I suspect the issue is somewhere in the calling code.

Comment: @Comintern You deleted his insolent rules, but I remember one of them "Examples are welcome, opinions are not.". As he already "tested this all in pieces" he might get better help somewhere else.

Comment: @Asger My comment above is not opinion. It is fact.  ;-)

Comment: use `Option explicit` and compile !

Comment: Why are you copying the input parameter to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Another more simple way to write a binary string to a file:

```
SUB WriteBinaryStringToFile (hex_val AS STRING)
    DIM handle AS LONG
    handle = FREEFILE
    OPEN "binary2.tst" FOR BINARY AS #handle
    SEEK #handle, LOF(handle) + 1
    PUT #handle, , hex_val
    CLOSE #handle
END SUB
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple method to write binary string to file:

```
SUB WriteBinaryStringToFile (hex_val AS STRING)
    DIM c AS STRING * 1
    DIM I AS LONG
    DIM handle AS LONG
    handle = FREEFILE
    OPEN "fp" FOR BINARY AS #handle
    FOR I = 1 TO LEN(hex_val)
        c = MID$(hex_val, I, 1)
        SEEK #handle, LOF(handle) + 1
        PUT #handle, , c
    NEXT I
    CLOSE #handle
END SUB
```

Comment: Maximum length of a string is 2,147,483,647 bytes.

Comment: If you don't do anything with the string (like OP with Split, as his string apparently contains |), then you could just `Put #handle, , hex_val` with the same result! Like Microsoft said: "Put writes variable-length strings that are not elements of user-defined types without the 2-byte length descriptor. The number of bytes written equals the number of characters in the string."

Comment: So, you are saying that if I open the file as binary I could put the entire string?

Comment: yes, just try it with "1234567890" :) https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/put-statement